# How to run a command in bash script which is not stopped when the script exits?

Tags: bash

I have a BASH script which runs other commands and I would like to keep them running in case the main script stops. I tried to run those commands with `&` but it didn't help. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry, what you mean by it didn't help?Please be more specific.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is normal: the shell's job control mechanism terminates its jobs when it exits.

There are at least two solutions:

- use `disown` after you have launched a job;
- use `at` to schedule your job at a later time;
- or use the `nohup` command.

Now, there is the question of what you want to do with the output of the command you launch in the background:

- with `disown`, you lose it;
- with `at`, stdout and stderr are sent to you by mail (but then you can redirect stdout/stderr if you want);
- with `nohup`, you define the output file yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Try 'nohup' command to run *COMMAND*, ignoring hangup signals

```
nohup COMMAND &
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using nohup (stands for no hangup) before your command:

```
nohup <your command>
```

It will forward the stdout of the command into a file called nohup.out by default.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example how to do this:

```
nohup your_command < /dev/null > output.log 2>&1 &
```

Comment: When providing a code sample you should precede it with 4 spaces so that it is formatted as a code sample.